# Is there good substitution for interface in has-a relationship in c++

Tags: c++, oop

I am facing an OOP problem in GUI design, but let me illustrate it with animals example. Lets have following setup:

- there is a base class Animal
- any derived class can *has-a* Teeth
- every animal with Teeth can Bite() <=> animals without Teeth cannot Bite()
- every animal Bite() the same way (there is default implementation in Teeth class)

It is only natural for animal *has-a* Teeth, but now I need something like interface for *has-a* relationship. For example, if I have a vector of animals, how can I make every Bite() if they can?

```
std::vector<Animal *> animals;
animals.push_back(new dog());
animals.push_back(new fly());
animals.push_back(new cat());

void Unleash_the_hounds(std::vector<Animal *> animals) 
{
    //bite if you can!
}
```

---

I came up with several solutions but none seems to be perfectly fitting:

1.) every class with Teeth also implements interface IBiting. This solution, however, introduces a lot of code duplication, I would need to "implement" Bite() in every class:

```
class Cat : public Animal, public IBiting {
    Teeth teeth;
public:
    virtual void Bite() { teeth.Bite(); }
}
```

2.) Give every animal Teeth, but only allow some to use them. *Note: syntax can be wrong - it is only illustration*

```
class Animal{
    static cosnt bool canBite = false;
    Teeth teeth;
public:
    void Bite() { this->canBite ? teeth.Bite() : return; }
}

class Cat {
    static cosnt bool canBite = true;
}
```

3.) More inheritance - create class BitingAnimal and derive it. Well, this could work, but what if I needed derive (non)flying animals, some of them have teeth.

```
class Animal{}
class BitingAnimal : public Animal {
    Teeth teeth;
}
```

and use as BitingAnimal.teeth.Bite()

4.) multiple inheritance. This often is discouraged, and impossible in most languages, plus it is not logical for Cat to be Teeth.

```
class Cat : public Animal, public Teeth {
}
```

5.) Enum of classes that can bite - weird only by sound of it.

---

*Or am I only over-complicating it and missed something important?*

Comment: Inheritance represents a "is-a" relationship. So your Cat is a Teeth in 4. I do not think it is the teeth that bite, despite they are part of the action of biting, there is more involved to it, maybe the mouth, but often the hole animal. Perhaps it would be better to have a special animal that is found of biting.

Comment: I have deleted my answer because you have better explanation of same idea there (I wanted to make you think and find the solution yourself to know why). If HasTeeth = CanBite, than use multiple inheritance and dynamic_cast ;)

Comment: Why are you storing two different concepts into a single container? Wouldn't `unleash_the_hounds(std::vector<BitingAnimal *>);` seem more appropriate to you?

Comment: Yes, it would, but introducing BitingAnimal (=using inheritance over composition) has problems as mentioned above - what if I had flying animal? Some can bite, others dont.

Comment: @wondra: virtual inheritance (of Animal) solves composition of BitingAnimal with FlyingAnimal (just like iostream = istream + ostream with virtual inheritance from ios).

Comment: @wondra what kind of real classes are we actually talking about? you're saying it's gui related. could you give a short and more concrete example?

Comment: @Alex It was meant for 1) container control and 2) control *has-a* border (and bite =render/get transformations for render). While first example could be probably solved best with Vaughn Cato´s answer, the 2nd one looks to fit multiple inheritance better. I looked in other GUI systems and they seem to use massive number of inheritance though.

Comment: @wondra I think your animals example is too vague in this case. Would a render pipeline approach make sense to you? as in you have a `can_be_rendered` interface and you can create a transformation from one can_be_rendered class into a different one with transformations? imagine something like the decorator pattern for a render function.

Comment: @Alex in the design, control is responsible for firing events and describing its visuals (nearly POD) so it could be easily described in a file. The renderer do(and store by handle) the drawing stuff - matrices, VBOs, textures. Since calculating matrices and allocating video memory is expensive, I found myself in need of has-a interface and dirty flags. I could use if(nullptr), but I would need it for every control feature(background,border,etc.) creating a monster UIelement class full of null pointers. There are always ways around, but I found the "*has-a* interface" question interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Interface is good and you can add default implementation this way:**

```
class IBiting { public virtual void bite() = 0 };
class HasTeeth, public IBiting { Teeth teeth; public:
    virtual void bite() override { teeth.bite(); } };

for(Animal* a: animals) {
    IBiting* it = dynamic_cast<IBiting*>(a);
    if(it) it->bite(); }
```

**1b) ...you can as well completly remove the interface and use only `HasTeeth`:**

```
class HasTeeth { Teeth teeth; public:
    void bite() { teeth.bite(); } };

for(Animal* a: animals) {
    HasTeeth* it = dynamic_cast<HasTeeth*>(a);
    if(it) it->bite(); }
```

**2) Bloating `Animal` can be used if you don't want to use RTTI/`dynamic_cast`.** You could make `virtual void bite()` with empty implementation on Animal and override it later (once adding `Teeth`). Not that much of coding if you insist not to use RTTI, but if you can use `dynamic_cast`, why not using it?

**EDIT:** The answer from *Vaughn Cato* is perfect for this - virtual/abstract `teethPtr()` (or `getTeeth()`) in Animal with *short-cuts* like `biteIfYouCan()`. Good for embedded world (microchips), but for PC, I still prefer `dynamic_cast`.

**3) [Virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) can help us with `BitingAnimal` vs. `FlyingAnimal`:**

```
class BitingAnimal: public virtual Animal {
Teeth teeth; public void bite() { teeth.bite(); } };
class FlyingAnimal: public virtual Animal {
Wings wings; public void fly() { wings.fly(); } };
class FlyingBitingAnimal: /*public virtual Animal, */
public FlyingAnimal, public BitingAnimal {};
```

**4) Joining `Animal` and `Teeth` has no sense unless you completely remove `Teeth` and replace it with `HasTeeth` or `CanBite`. Then it becomes my *1b*.**

**5) That enum is another version of 2 - bloating animal. Not good.**
But that leads me to alternative not using dynamic_cast: you can mimic it by **capabilities** (that enum, or flags on animal - `bool can_bite`) that can tell you, wich cast is safe. Then you can use multiple/virtual inheritance to mimic dynamic_cast (check capability first, cast next).

**EDIT:** *Vaughn Cato*'s `teethPtr()` matches this as well (***show me the teeth you can bite with if you have them***) and does not need the cast.

---

**Answer to comment:**

***In short:*** try to name a feature (capability, ability to do something, to provide something).

***Long answer:*** Do you need `Teeth` and `HasTeeth` or single `CanBite`? Your 4th solution is not bad in the principle, but in naming and therefore other possibilities. All this was hypothetical. Interfaces are well known in other languages (single inheritance + interfaces), `HasTeeth` is something like C# [`IListSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with `IList GetList()` and `bool ContainsList` (for erasure) where the `bite()` is not there directly, but can be added by extension method:

```
static IEnumerator GetEnumerator(this IListSource it) {
    if(!it.ContainsList) yield break;
    foreach(object o in it.GetList()) yield return o; }
```

Here you can see, that I have achieved same thing with C# extension method as with C++ multiple inheritance. The name is **is-a** form - **SourceOf**. Can you share the real names from your GUI with us?

**Example from C++ would be [iostream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_iostream) = istream + ostream with virtual inheritance from ios.** Again ***is-a*** naming.

Comment: I can see, most answers recommend multiple inheritance of "interface" with *has-a* member (or as Kao called it, mixin). Are there any good naming conventions? I mean, while `HasTeeth` is more clear alone, `Cat` certainly not *is-a* `HasTeeth`.

Comment: For C++, I would use virtual inheritance and BitingAnimal (Cat is-a BitingAnimal).

Answer (score 2):

An alternative that you didn't mention is to just provide an abstraction for the teeth, but implement the biting in the base class.  This reduces the duplication because the derived classes only need to specify how to access the teeth instead of how to bite.  By returning a pointer to the teeth, we can allow a null pointer to indicate that the animal has no teeth.  Here is an example:

```
#include <vector>

struct Teeth {
  void bite() { }
};

struct Animal {
  virtual Teeth *teethPtr() = 0;

  void biteIfYouCan() { if (teethPtr()) teethPtr()->bite(); }
};

struct Dog : Animal {
  Teeth teeth;
  Teeth *teethPtr() override { return &teeth; }
};

struct Fish : Animal {
  Teeth *teethPtr() override { return nullptr; }
};

int main()
{
  Dog dog;
  Fish fish;

  std::vector<Animal *> animals {&dog,&fish};

  for (auto animal_ptr : animals) {
    animal_ptr->biteIfYouCan();
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly like C# IListSource I have mentioned - ***show me the teeth you can bite with if you have them***. But that one contains the code duplication (override teethPtr whenever adding teeth).

Comment: @firda: I do like how your version with `dynamic_cast` requires less code in the derived classes.  I think using the virtual `teethPtr` method can have advantages also though.  For example, when implementing a new derived class, you are forced to think about the need for teeth and make a decision about whether you want to provide them or not.  Using the `dynamic_cast` approach, you might not realize there is a `HasTeeth` base class that you are supposed to derive from, and instead just add the `Teeth` directly as a member.

Comment: I like to use abstract methods as well (to make myself think about it when I create descendant class, especially after long time forgetting about it). For PC app I'd use dynamic_cast, but for embedded software (firmware, microchips), I'd go your way (or my version of solution2 - your answer matches it quite well, yours think about other methods of Teeth, single override in descendants, duplication in Teeth and Animal only).

Answer (score 1):

Here are my comments to your solutions:

1. I agree with you that this will result in a lot of code duplication. Not cool.
2. This clearly isn't the best way. Using `canBite` flag is a symptome, that it can be done better.
3. Again, bad design - calling `BitingAnimal.teeth.Bite()` is a violation of [Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Also, as you described - what if an Animal which is not `BittingAnimal` would like to bite?
4. As Mare Infinitus commented, in this approach your `Cat` **is a** `Teeth`. This is not *entirely* correct.
5. Enum of classes that can bite  - you're right. This is weird :)

I'd suggest following approach: create  `IBiting` interface and its implementation `Biting` in a [mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin)-like way:

```
class Bitting : public IBiting {
    Teeth teeth;
public:
    virtual void Bite() { teeth.Bite(); }
}
```

then, each class which can bite, will inherit from `Biting` "mixin":

```
class Cat : public Animal, public Biting {
}
```

This will be a multiple inheritance, of course, but, since `Biting` only implements a "Biting" functionality, it won't be so bad (no [Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem)).

Comment: As beginner to c++ I am only a bit confused - why are you taking the long way around? Can you explain why is better to inherit from Biting instead of Teeth (except, direct is-a is logical nonsense)? (plus why Bitting need to implement IBiting, it looks for me like an interface with member)

Comment: @wondra, "why is better to inherit from Biting instead of Teeth" well, apart from the fact that this is a nonsense, suppose, for example, that you will add new method to `Teeth` called `Brush()`. Then you could call `Cat.Brush()` and this would be confusing. And nonsense.

Comment: @wondra "why Bitting need to implement IBiting" this is not just an interface with a member, it also provides (by delegation) implementation of Bite() method.

Answer (score 1):

The question boils down to what should happen if you call `animal->bite()` and that animal does not have teeth and cannot bite. One answer could be that *all animals can bite*. For cats it has an effect due to them having teeth whereas other animals such as butterflies can bite but nothing happens.

```
class Animal{
    public:
    virtual void bite(){}
};

class Cat : public Animal{
    Teeth teeth;
    void bite() override{
        teeth.bite();
    }
};

class Butterfly : public Animal{
};
```

In this approach you do need to write for every animal type extra how it bites if it can. It becomes a bit more tricky if you need other attributes like `scream()` and `fly()`. Yes cats can fly in this model, it is just that nothing at all happens when they do and butterflies can scream with a volume of zero.

Since there are a lot of animals who have teeth and they all bite the same way you could add a few specialized animals.

```
class BitingWithTeethAnimal : public Animal{
    Teeth teeth;
    void bite() override{
        teeth.bite();
    }
};

class Cat : public BitingWithTeethAnimal{
};

class Butterfly : public FlyingWithWingsAnimal{
};
```

Ideally you would be able to say something like `class Pterodactyl : public BitingWithTeeth, FlyingWithWings, ScreamingWithVoice, Animal;` without bloating `Animal` to a monster class but that is not possible in my implementation. The upside though is that you only implement the things you need and you never get confused when an animal can bite with its teeth and also with its beak since the implementation is in one function and not separated in different classes.

[image: Pterodactyl]

Comment: why not `Biting<Teeth>` and so on, more generic, more extensible

Comment: @ddriver Should `Biting<Teeth>` be an object or a function or a class?

Comment: Wouldnt `class Pterodactyl : public BitingWithTeeth, FlyingWithWings, ScreamingWithVoice, Animal;` lead to diamond problem later? After all, all those classes inherit from Animal.

Comment: @wondra Yes it would. That is why I wrote "but that is not possible in my implementation".

Answer (score 0):

### ***This answer is no longer valid, once we made clear that:***

**every animal with Teeth can Bite() <=> animals without Teeth cannot Bite()**

***This leads to less separation. There are better answers, but I have undeleted this one to show my thoughts about the design:***

---

**Original:**

```
class Animal { public: virtual ~Animal() {} /* for RTTI */ };
class IBite { virtual void Bite() = 0; };                  // interface
class Teeth: public IBite { public: void Bite() { ... } }; // implementation
class HasTeeth { protected: Teeth teeth; }; // part of thought process
class BiteWithTeeth: public HasTeeth, public IBite {       // interface
public: void Bite() { teeth.Bite(); } };                   // +implementation
class Cat: public Animal, public BiteWithTeeth {};         // final class
class Unknown: public Animal, public HashTeeth {}; // but no IBite - not allowed
```

The order above should make you think why. It involves using `dynamic_cast` to find the interface (solution will be different if you insist not using it). ***I prefer to separate things that are not related and find the smallest things (classes/interfaces) that are truly related (otherwise you will do that later when you find that you need it - if you ever need to separate bite from teeth).***

```
class AnimalBitingWithTeeth: public Animal, public BiteWithTeeth {};
class AnimalWithTeethButNotBiting: public Animal, public HashTeeth {};
```

We need `Animal` as base class and `IBite` (or `IBiting`) to mark some feature. Other classes allow us to implement that feature (e.g. `BiteWithTeeth`) but allow other implementations as well.

Important question is: Can we have a chain where IBite will be included but we want to disable it then? We can reimplement (virtual) Bite with empty or add `virtual bool CanBite()` if we need to ask such question (instead of *bite if you can*). ***It is crutial to find correct questions (and features) in OOP to create good design.***

---

***See my second answer for the solution - multiple/virtual inheritance.***

Comment: I prefer separation. You can add `class AnimalBittingWithTeeth` as a base class for `Cat` and any such. Use `dynamic_cast` to find the interface (if it is there).

Comment: You prefer composite interface (is-a/can do) and field(has-a) into a class, that will be used instead of the interface, did I get it right?

Comment: The question is what do **you** need. List of Animals and function **for each: bite if you can**? I have introduced interface (for Bite) and helper classes for **bite with teeth** and possible **has teeth, but don't bite**.

Comment: Actually, it is not intended for anything else to Bite(), and as for now there should be only one implementation of Bite(). What does not have teeth cannot bite.

Comment: If you know, that what does not have teeth cannot bite, you don't need to separate it. That's it. `HaveTeeth` should therefore include *bite with teeth*. That is exactly the way of thinking you need for good OOP design. But be careful, do all animals with teeth bite? Can animal bite with something we won't call teeth? These are questions you have to ask yourself. Answers should lead to design.

Answer (score 0):

It's a code smell to put things into the same container that don't share something.
Query for the right container instead of query the class of it's capabilities.

If you really want to have a single creating instance use a helper class. But try to use interfaces for classes that have something in **common**. Imagine if you have 5000 animal types and two of them can bite. Do you really want to look through each of them to go an check each of them for teeth? You already know you only have two dogs at the time you acquire them.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Animal { virtual ~Animal() {} }; // used to tag elements
struct Biting : public Animal {  virtual void bite() = 0;  };
struct Flying : public Animal {  virtual void fly() = 0; };
struct Bird : public Flying {
    virtual void fly() override { cout << "Fly\n"; }
};  
struct Dog : public Biting {
    virtual void bite() override { cout << "Bite\n"; }
};  
struct World {
    void populate(Animal *animal) {
        Biting *b = dynamic_cast<Biting *>(animal);
        if (b != nullptr) {
            Biters.push_back(b);
            return;
        }   
        Flying *f = dynamic_cast<Flying *>(animal);
        if (f != nullptr) {
            Flyers.push_back(f);
            return;
        }   
    }   

    std::vector<Biting *> Biters;
    std::vector<Flying *> Flyers;
};  

class Schaefer : public Dog { };
class Pitbull : public Dog { };
class KingFisher : public Bird { };
class WoodPecker : public Bird { };

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    World w; 

    Schaefer s;
    Pitbull p;

    KingFisher k;
    WoodPecker wp;


    w.populate(&s);
    w.populate(&p);
    w.populate(&k);
    w.populate(&wp);

    for (auto &i : w.Biters) {
        i->bite(); 
    }   

    for (auto &i : w.Flyers) {
        i->fly();
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the important clarifying means: would biting change the dog (loosing teeth, dying from infection?) would unleashing the dogs modify other animals of the world or would the dogs stop being part of a cage/the world? is unleashing potentially targeted to something? Would type erasure be of help? (be aware of dragons from this point on: http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/oz18T05o/)